# Could there have been a better way to code this? (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, html-lists, appendchild

Note: i'm trying to learn how to use javascript not jquery or other libraries.

I'm new to javascript and I want to learn how it works and wanted to know if there was a more effective way of coding this.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var domObject = document.createElement("li"),
        userName = document.getElementById("userName").value,
        userNameText = document.createTextNode(userName);

    domObject.appendChild(userNameText);
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(domObject);
    document.getElementById("userName").value = "";
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input type="text" id="userName">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
    <ul id="myList">
        <li>this is</li>
        <li>just a</li>
        <li>test to</li>
        <li>append children</li>
    </ul>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for peer review of working code. It is better suited for [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`domObject` is certainly not the best name for a variable (nor is `myFunction`). Anyway, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event listeners:

```js
// you can, of course, use getElementById with an ID attribute
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var list = document.querySelector('ul');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = input.value;
  input.value = '';
  list.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>Add to list</button>
<ul></ul>
```